# How to disable the video output of an html5 video player

Tags: html, video, output, mute

the html5 video player has the mute attribute to mute the audio output, is there someway to "mute" the video output or disable it leaving the audio only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could supposedly use the [videoTracks API](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#dom-media-videotracks). Though I'm not exactly sure how many browsers support that yet.

```
var video = document.getElementById('myVideoId');

video.onloadedmetadata = function (event) {
  video.videoTracks[0].selected = false;
};
```

Comment: This would be the correct way to do it, but according to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_video_videotracks.asp) no major browser has it yet. Thank you.

Comment: I take back the previous last sentence, according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Browser_compatibility) firefox has it since v33.0 which has been released on 2014-10

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can make it's width, height to 0 and start it with autoplay or javascript.

here I edited another questions fiddle to make a little demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jzs6B/1043/

```
    $("#videoarea").css({
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    });
```

Comment: this is good idea thank you, but I would have to make my own controls as the original controls disappear.

Comment: if you like to have browsers controls, make it's height to 0 and width to proper pixel like 640px or your default video size. like so http://jsfiddle.net/Jzs6B/1063/

Comment: The whole thing disappears for me (I'm on firefox 34), it stays proportional.